# Time Defferance between two Times in LINQ to Entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

```
var TimeNow = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

var qq = from s in _EeHC_HrEntities.TransactionsSecretaries
         where (EntityFunctions.CreateTime(s.TransactionTime.Hours,
                                           s.TransactionTime.Minutes,
                                           s.TransactionTime.Seconds) >
                EntityFunctions.CreateTime(TimeNow.Hours,
                                           TimeNow.Minutes,
                                           TimeNow.Seconds))
```

I want compare between two times and display the data that data.time in dataebase > DateTimeNow.time but the result  display not True

Comment: Entity Framework doesn't really run your queries, but just creates SQL queries based on your query expression. Try simplifying the expression, and for a test, try to to do a simple `where (s.TransactionTime.Minutes > 30)`

Comment: using > is not good try to use `>=` when comparing time.. also do not use `Between` you would get mega `UnExpected Results`

Answer (score 0):

```
**becouse th 24 hours convert to 12 hours it will work thanx for answers** 

var TimeNow = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    var TimeHourNow = (TimeNow.Hours < 12) ? TimeNow.Hours : (TimeNow.Hours - 12);


var qq = from s in _EeHC_HrEntities.TransactionsSecretaries
         where (EntityFunctions.CreateTime(s.TransactionTime.Hours, s.TransactionTime.Minutes, s.TransactionTime.Seconds) > EntityFunctions.CreateTime(TimeHourNow, TimeNow.Minutes, TimeNow.Seconds))
```